# Adobe analytics for Angular web application

Tags: angular, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am new to Angular, we need to integrate Adobe Analytics to our web site, i.e we need it to be on every single page/component as we call it, the issue is i can add it only on the index.html page, i am not sure on how to achieve it on all pages, any help or guidance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you add Adobe Analytics to your index.html, it **will** appear on all pages.

You may then need to look into how it can properly fire events in response to Route changes etc.

Comment: i have added the Adobe Analytics to my index.html page and used the the NavigationEnd and NavigationStart event for firing the event, the event gets fired but the datalayer is not getting created.